# SQL script and random variables in queries

Tags: mysql, sql

I started writing an sql script for which I'm trying to make a procedure that creates an insert query using a random variable between 2 integers

This is what I have so far:

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE REL9()
BEGIN
  DECLARE k INT DEFAULT 1;

DECLARE Random INT;
DECLARE Upper INT DEFAULT 9999;
DECLARE Lower INT DEFAULT 1;

  WHILE k < 20 DO
   SET Random = ROUND(((Upper - Lower -1) * RAND() + Lower), 0);
        INSERT INTO `sc_db`.`relations` (`idRelations`, `cdate`, `rel_type`, `port_cdom`, `host_cdom`, `dom_idObjects`, `cdom_idObjects`, `rel_name`) VALUES (NULL, '5555', 'Transitive', 'localhost', 'localhost', 'Random', 'Random', 'IS_IN');

    SET k = k + 1;
  END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

When calling the procedure I get a foreign key error, most likely due to the random variable not being set or called correctly. Those 'random' keys (1 to 9999) do exist in the database.
 How to include a variable inside the insertion values? I've searched the web and some results say variables can be prefixed with @, but I get an error that way for some reason.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: I always thought that MySQL formatting required an @ as a prefix for a variable. Like Marc mentioned, when put a string between ', it's interpreted as a string, not a variable. Does your code even compile? Also.. are you trying to add a different random number to all 20 entries?? If so, you're a bit off.

Answer (score 1):

You're not inserting your random value, you're inserting a STRING that contains the word `Random`:

```
[...snip...] 'localhost', 'Random', 'Random', 'IS_IN');
                          ^------^--^------^---
```

With the quotes: a string with the characters `R`, `a`, `n`, etc...
Without the quotes: A variable named `Random`

Comment: that is not exactly the solution

Comment: exactly how is it not the solution?

Comment: Figured it would be something as simple as that. Just started learning this. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you'd like to have a different random number for each inserts..

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE REL9()
BEGIN
  DECLARE @k INT DEFAULT 1;

DECLARE @Random INT;
DECLARE @Upper INT DEFAULT 9999;
DECLARE @Lower INT DEFAULT 1;

  WHILE k < 20 DO
        SET @Random = ROUND(((@Upper - @Lower -1) * RAND() + @Lower), 0);

        INSERT INTO `sc_db`.`relations` (`idRelations`, `cdate`, `rel_type`, `port_cdom`, `host_cdom`, `dom_idObjects`, `cdom_idObjects`, `rel_name`) VALUES (NULL, '5555', 'Transitive', 'localhost', 'localhost', @Random, @Random, 'IS_IN');

    SET @k = @k + 1; 
#Or @k -= 1;
  END WHILE;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

Also, what are those? `dom_idObjects`, `cdom_idObjects`.
If the '@' doesn't work, you're using a different compiler. Can you provide more details?

Comment: Yeah, that was a mistake while copying. My bad. The compiler still won't accept @ in variable names. Right now I'm using the phpmyadmin in windows v4.1.14 to test the script. dom_idObjects, cdom_idObjects are foreign keys to another table for which I already have 10.000 records.

Comment: Very well, those idObjects are FK. In this case, why would they be assigned to random? If your compiler does not recognize the '@', simply remove the '@' signs and try running it.